# countourf doesn't show colored regions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

What should I change in my code that countorf shows regions with more color differences?

```
clear all;
close all;
phi=90;
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(-20:0.1:20,-20:0.1:20);
Idontwantthis = (xx.^2+yy.^2)<0.1;
u = (xx./(xx.^2+yy.^2).^(3/2));
v = (yy./(xx.^2+yy.^2).^(3/2));
data= sqrt(u.^2+v.^2);
data(Idontwantthis)=NaN;
u(Idontwantthis)=NaN;
v(Idontwantthis)=NaN;
contourf(xx,yy,data,20);
```

Comment: This code isn't fully reproducible. Post the full code, e.g. where do you set `x` and `y`? Have you tried changing the `colormap`?

Comment: Sorry, Done. @kedarps

Comment: Try using `contour` instead of `contourf`.

Comment: I want colored regions @kedarps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need `meshgrid` over `[-20 20]`. Try reducing the range to like `[-2 2]`. After you run `contourf`, change colormap:

```
clear all;
close all;
phi=90;

[xx,yy] = meshgrid(-2:0.01:2,-2:0.01:2);

Idontwantthis = (xx.^2+yy.^2)<0.1;
u = (xx./(xx.^2+yy.^2).^(3/2));
v = (yy./(xx.^2+yy.^2).^(3/2));
data= sqrt(u.^2+v.^2);
data(Idontwantthis)=NaN;
u(Idontwantthis)=NaN;
v(Idontwantthis)=NaN;

contourf(xx,yy,data,20);
colormap hsv;
```

This is what your result will look like:
[image: contour plot with hsv colormap]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great! Thanks. ++